# how I can Specifying tcpreplay speed

Tags: networking, tcpreplay

I am tring to Specify tcpreplay speed but I can't do it 
this is my detail of test:

$tcpreplay -V
tcpreplay version: 3.4.4 (build 2450)

1)$  tcpreplay -i %0 -p 100 -L 500  _udp_only.pcap
Actual: 500 packets (42247 bytes) sent in 5.05 seconds.Rated: 8365.7 bps, 0.06 Mbps, 99.01 pps
s

2)$  tcpreplay -i %0 -p 1000 -L 5000  _udp_only.pcap
Actual: 5000 packets (427710 bytes) sent in 5.19 seconds.               Rated: 82410.4 bps, 0.63 Mbps, 963.39 pps

//here is problem I stay in 966.00 pps

3)$  tcpreplay -i %0 -p 10000 -L 50000 _udp_only.pcap
Actual: 50000 packets (4322559 bytes) sent in 51.76 seconds.Rated: 83511.6 bps, 0.64 Mbps, 966.00 pps

I have same problem when I try to Specify --mbps
for 8600 packets 86 byte avg for each packet

-M0.086 -L 860 ---->  Rated: 10812.9 bps, 0.08 Mbps, 127.22 pps

-M0.86 -L 860  ---->  Rated: 83062.5 bps, 0.63 Mbps, 977.27 pps

-M0.86 -L 8600 ---->   Rated: 82554.9 bps, 0.63 Mbps, 965.21 pps

why and how I can to Specify speed?

I use OS windows7

Comment: Can you verify that some resource on your system isn't being saturated such as you processor or network interface?

Comment: my computer in rest and I try it from some other machine I think problem is parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few comments:

1. Windows support in tcpreplay is pretty much of a beta quality.  High precision timing turns out to be very OS and hardware specific and Windows has the least amount of testing & development.  You'll have better luck under Linux or OS X.
2. Small packets + using the --mbps option (-M) is pretty much a worst case scenario for accurate packet timing.  Using -M requires tcpreplay to dynamically calculate delays (more CPU intensive) and small packets makes even small inaccuracies in sending the packets look a lot worse when compared to larger packets.
3. Your run of "-M0.086 -L 860 ----> Rated: 10812.9 bps, 0.08 Mbps, 127.22 pps" is pretty damn close.  Tcpreplay only prints out two significant figures, so 0.08 for 0.086 is as "close" as you can expect.

Comment: +1, but wouldn't .086 round to .09 instead of .08? Also keep in mind that depending on the actual packets being replayed, they may not round evenly into the time frame/speed you are attempting to achieve.

Comment: @Aron but when I try use pps Specify have also problem -L10000 -P2000 --> 1000.00 pps I can't pass 1000 pps